# Monk casting Electric Arc from Wisdom

Tags: spellcasting, monk, pathfinder-2e

I have this character concept, an Archer Monk, that uses the the first action for Flurry of Blows then Electric Arc from the other two, because that does not care about MAP<sup>1</sup>.
To make it work with Ki Spells, it has to be Wisdom based<sup>2</sup>. To scale in proficiency, it has to be Divine<sup>3</sup>.

So on 2nd level he takes Cleric Dedication, and then on 3rd Ancestral Paragon -> Adopted Cantrip. Unfortunately, this locks the race to Human, unless I want to wait until 5th level<sup>4</sup>.
**Is there any way to make it work on level 3 with any other race?**

Conditions:

- Electric Arc is a must
- Divine or Occult spellcasting is a must, so that it improves together with Ki spells
- Wisdom is preferred, Charisma is acceptable

---

1. A 3rd and 4th attack with the bow are highly unlikely to hit.
2. Or I could just take Focus Spells that do not care about my Wisdom, but I really like Ki Blast.
3. I do not intend to take Basic, Expert and Master spellcasting
4. Adopted Ancestry (Human) on level 3, then Adapted Cantrip on level 5

Comment: Preferably PFS legal.

Comment: would you be okay with an answer that used Occult instead of Divine, since you have that option as a monk? I don't think it's likely either way, but that does increase the odd.

Comment: @ESCE, it would be okay, I will ask a separate question about the need for Wisdom

Comment: Finding all 3 of Divine-Wisdom-Electric Arc is pretty difficult. I found ways that satisfy either Divine or Wisdom. You're not interested in any of those, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Take Druid Dedication, you can retrain it later

The scaling of Occult or Divine spellcasting is important only when it improves over trained. That happens with Monk Expertise on level 9, so you have plenty of time to take a General feat (Adopted Ancestry) and an Ancestry feat (Adapted Cantrip) with any race.

I would retrain Druid to Cleric dedication just before I reach level 5.

Answer (score 3):

### Electric Arc as an innate (Charisma) Occult or Divine spell

[Virga May](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2334) (Storm Hag) Changelings (a versatile heritage, although somewhat lore-locked) can start with Electric Arc as an occult cantrip.

[Wellspring Gnome](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=15) with [First World Magic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=28) can start with a primal cantrip but casts it as an innate arcane, occult, or divine (chosen at character creation). Bonus, they get another (occult or divine, in this case) cantrip for when you don't want to use Electric Arc.

---

Why Charisma?

From [Innate spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=279)

> You use your Charisma modifier as your spellcasting ability modifier for innate spells **unless otherwise specified.**

You *may* be able to convince your GM to allow you to use Wisdom for innate divine spell(s), although this obviously doesn't fly in PFS.

---

Honorable mentions:

- [Magaambyan Attendant Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1102) allows you to take it as a primal spell that uses Wisdom but not divine/occult.
- Tengu can take Storm's Lash to cast Electric Arc as a primal innate spell.
- Elf (and half-Elf) can take Wildborn Magic to gain a primal cantrip innate cantrip or Otherwordly Magic to gain an arcane innate cantrip.
- Lizardfolk can take Bone Magic to gain a primal catrip innate spell.
- [Wayfinder Resonance Tinkerer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=875) allows you to cast it through a Wayfinder with almost no rule clarifications (it seems to assume using it like another item activation, but doesn't specify if the spell is heightened to your level, the Wayfinder's level, or something else nor what you use for the spell attack/DC if applicable)

Comment: Otherwordly Magic also works as well as Wildborn Magic

Comment: Ah yeah. There are actually a *ton* of ways to get an arcane cantrip. I was mostly looking at primal when I made that list b/c someone *might* be able to convince their GM to let them use Wisdom instead of Charisma. I'll add that one since its directly related to elves, but I don't intend to make that list exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

## Sort of

You can make your concept with an [Archaic Wayfinder](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=470) and a friend that can cast Electric Arc. This would allow your Monk to cast it once per combat* fairly easily until you are able to pick it up yourself, and Archaic Wayfinder is available at level 2 and you should have access to it in PFS (although I'm not actually familiar with the PFS rules, AoN says all characters have access to it in PFS). This seems like it should use your friend's Spellcasting DC, since it says:

> Activating an archaic wayfinder is the same as the casting for the relevant spell

I believe this is the only pre-level 4 way to fulfill your concept. This may be enough to tide you over until level 5, when you can take Adapted Cantrip with whatever ancestry you want. It's obviously hard to prove a negative, but I could find no archetype dedications that would allow you to mimic the behavior of Adapted Cantrip to get Electric Arc as a Divine nor Occult non-innate Spell.

*Technically you could do it multiple times per combat if your friend keeps spending their actions to refill it, but that's 4 actions between the both of you to cast it.

Comment: Would it be cast with Wisdom?

Comment: It would be cast as if the caster who stored Electric Arc into the Archaic Wayfinder cast it. So it could be cast with Wisdom by the original caster (Druid, Cleric w/ Adapted Cantrip), but it doesn't matter much to your character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jolt Coil](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2231)

You do not even need Adopted Ancestry and Adapted Cantrip any more, [but apparently you need the Basic Spellcasting feat on top of a multiclass that casts spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204986/49393), and slap a Spellheart on your weapon for 60 gp.

It will use your spell DC, based on your Wisdom. You can even pick occult for the tradition of your Ki spells.

Comment: I don't believe this works, as Monks do not get the Cast a Spell activity. Similar to how Monks couldn't just cast any old occult or divine scroll. Real casters (e.g. Wizards) do get that Cast a Spell activity, which allows them to use Scrolls and Spellhearts.

Comment: The rule you linked means the opposite of how you are reading it: "**You gain the ability to Cast a Spell** and use any spellcasting actions necessary **to cast your focus spells** (see below). However, **you don’t qualify for** feats and **other rules that require you to be a spellcaster**." You get the ability to cast focus spells only. The 'cast a spell' of the 'activate an item' activity is exactly a rule that requires you to be a spellcaster, as it says: "You must have a spellcasting class feature to Activate an Item with this activation component."

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204980/does-cast-a-spell-make-you-a-spellcaster discusses the viability of this answer.

Comment: @ESCE, the answer has changed