# Which Ki spells care about Wisdom?

Tags: spells, monk, pathfinder-2e

Came up about [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185404/monk-casting-electric-arc-from-wisdom?noredirect=1#comment501931_185404).

Most monk Ki spells do not care about your Wisdom, being mainly buffs.
I found only one where your Wisdom is important; Ki Blast (for the save DC). **Are there any more?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monk Focus Spells can be found [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/SpellLists.aspx?Trait=112). Some do allow Saves.

- Ki Blast (Fortitude Save)
- Wronged Monk's Wrath (Reflex save)
- Shadow's Web (Fortitude Save)
- Medusa's Wrath (Fortitude Save to end the effect)
- Quivering Palm (Fortitude Save when 'triggered')

Additionally, some Ki spells have Counteract checks associated, which use your Wisdom as part of the bonus.

- Wholeness of Body

  - Allows you to Counteract poison and disease
- Ki Form

  - Ki Form's corona attempts to counteract darkness effects